# How to get sever date as defaultly selected in client side system calender in coldfusion?

Tags: datefield

Hai, I'm Deepa.I'm in an issue in coldfusion development.my doubt is that
how i got the current date as defaultly selected in my client pc,
while the client system date is wrong bt the server date is correct. 
I used the cfinput datefield,bt i got the client system date as defaultly
 selected in my datefield calender. The issue is that if whatever the client system date, i want the server date as default in clientside calender. can you help me